# MSBuild error MSB4057 after updating to VS 2019 16.10.0

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

The command below worked flawlessly before updating to VS 2019 16.10.0:

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Project1;Project2;Project3 /p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugType=None /p:OutputPath="C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Build"
```

After the update I'm getting the message **error MSB4057: the target "Project1" does not exist in the project** when I try the command in Developer Command Prompt of VS 2019.

Comment: I reported this bug in https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/6499

Comment: @José They fixed it in 16.10.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until Microsoft releases an update we found that you can add **:Rebuild** to the end of your projects and that fixed it for us.

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Project1:Rebuild;Project2:Rebuild;Project3:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugType=None /p:OutputPath="C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Build"
```

Comment: They fixed it in 16.10.1

Comment: It is still broken.Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951994/unable-to-invoke-build-target-using-msbuild-command-line-on-a-solution-file

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative if you like to avoid the rebuild suggested by the accepted answer:

- Add a custom target to the project files like `<Target Name="MyBuild" DependsOnTargets="Build" />`
- Call this target from the script, e.g. `msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Project1:MyBuild;Project2:MyBuild;Project3:MyBuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugType=None /p:OutputPath="C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Build"`