# Unable to invoke Build target using msbuild command line on a solution file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with many projects organized in solution folders. I am trying to invoke Build target on a project of the solution using solution .sln file. The msbuild errs out saying Build target is not available in the said project. I can invoke Clean target, Rebuild target on the same project, but not build.

Wondering what I am doing wrong.
Below is the command line that I am using:

> msbuild ..\Galaxy.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:"Platform=Any CPU"
> /t:"DataTools\CLIUtils:Build"

The error:
error MSB4057: The target "DataTools\CLIUtils:Build" does not exist in the project. [*snip*\Galaxy.sln]

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I also checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2015 which describes target invocation for solutions. This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Check the build target in DataTools\CLIUtils. Or you can also try to update the visual studio to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Build target is default target that the framework provides right? I don't know what to check there?
Let me see if I have a system with VS 2022 and check if this issue is still there.

Comment: I tried with VS 2022. I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

We can produce an MSBuild file named .sln.metaproj use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2022#troubleshooting) method and check this file we can see targets like Clean, Rebuild, Publish, Restore but not Build target.

[image]

You can try CoreBuild target, it works in my test:

```
msbuild ..\Galaxy.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:"Platform=Any CPU" /t:"DataTools\CLIUtils:CoreBuild"
```

Comment: You are right. I don't see Build target in the .sln.metaproj for DataTools\CLIUtils:Build. The CoreBuild seemed like it worked, but it didn't. I have Directory.Build.targets file with bunch of targets tied to AfterBuild target. They didn't get invoked with CoreBuild.
The meta project is helping me understand how solution invokes project targets. I am coming up with set of targets at solution level using Directory.Solution.targets file

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069805/17296043) about AfterBuild target in Directory.Build.targets file. Or you can create a new question about this.